# Add a call function to modem-manager-gui

Tags: networking, usb-modem, modem-manager

**Modem Manager GUI** is very helpful tool for EDGE/3G/4G modem specific functions control.

I am using `modem-manager-gui` 0.0.16-2 with Ubuntu 14.04:

[image: screen-shot]

It has very useful functions like SMS, USSD, Traffic, Limit Data, etc. **But there is not any Call function.**

**So, Can it facilities with call function?**

Comment: [Wammu](http://wammu.eu/) has a call function but only for few devices, seems to be your device is [not supported for calls](http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/).

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I’m in need of something similar

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri I had not get solution at that time. Well, I do not use USB Modem now a days.

Comment: Thanks @Pandya - Can I pls ask what you use instead? I want to make/receive calls and texts and use data. Preferably 4g

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri I use USB Tethering from Android Mobile Phone to connect Desktop with internet and Portable Wifi Hotspot to connect Laptop with internet.

Comment: Ok thank you @Pandya