# Any app/GUI to manage a Huawei USB dongle?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, usb-modem

Currently using a Huawei USB dongle which works perfectly out of the box with 14.04. Only thing I need now is a linux version of the GUI which enables users to send messages, make calls et al. Anything like that out there?

Comment: Try `modem-manager-gui`

Comment: @Pandya it certainly offers the closest functionality as the windows app which comes bundled with the dongle. Can you post this solution as an answer with the relevant terminal instructions or should I do that myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excellent tool I was directed to helps in managing the `Modem Manager GUI` Modem Manager GUI is frontend for ModemManager daemon able to control specific modem functions. The main features listed on the project [website](http://linuxonly.ru/cms/page.php?7) are:

- GTK3 interface
- Send and receive SMS messages with messages concatenation
- Send USSD request and receive answer in system encoding
- Get modem and SIM information (Device info, Operator name, Mode, IMEI, IMSI/ESN, Signal level)
- Scan available mobile networks
  Control data transmission process and set session traffic and time limits

USSD requests works perfectly. Can send and receive SMS but it seems the messages don't get saved on the sim but only displays via Notify-OSD

Finally as noted already in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466364/add-a-call-function-to-modem-manager-gui), the call function doesn't work with this tool. To get this function working again, **wammu and gammu packages** from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ppa) should be added by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wammu gammu
```

NOTE: Not all dongles are supported. Here is a [list](http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/) of all the Huawei dongles supported along with the supported feature

Comment: Also [visit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/466364/)

Comment: Note: there could be a problem with wammu/gammu installation in a bit older distro, like LTS. [I found a nice solution](http://www.pygopar.com/installing-wxpython-3-on-ubuntu14-04/), which is in short in temporary adding the latest repository, installing the apps, and removing repository. Don't forget to change in the commands of the article the name of distro which has the program *(for me it is wily)*.